# which coefficients go to which class in multiclass logistic regression in scikit learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I'm using scikit learn's Logistic Regression for a multiclass problem.

```
logit = LogisticRegression(penalty='l1')
logit = logit.fit(X, y)
```

I'm interested in which features are driving this decision.

```
logit.coef_
```

The above gives me a beautiful dataframe in `(n_classes, n_features)` format,  but all the classes and feature names are gone. With features, that's okay, because making the assumption that they're indexed the same way as I passed them in seems safe...

But with classes, it's a problem, since I never explicitly passed in the classes in any order. So which class do coefficient sets (rows in the dataframe) 0, 1, 2, and 3 belong to?

Comment: It will simply be ordered from index 0 to `n_classses-1`. Did you pass numeric or strings in `y`? If strings then LabelEncoder will be used on it to convert to numeric form. Can you show your `y` here?

Comment: Strings. labels are: `array(['GR3', 'GR4', 'SHH', 'GR3', 'GR4', 'SHH', 'GR4', 'SHH', 'GR4',
       'WNT', 'GR3', 'GR4', 'GR3', 'SHH', 'SHH', 'GR3', 'GR4', 'SHH',
       'GR4', 'GR3', 'SHH', 'GR3', 'SHH', 'GR4', 'SHH', 'GR3', 'GR4',
       'GR4', 'SHH', 'GR4', 'SHH', 'GR4', 'GR3', 'GR3', 'WNT', 'SHH',
       'GR4', 'SHH', 'SHH', 'GR3', 'WNT', 'GR3', 'GR4', 'GR3', 'SHH'], dtype=object)` and I get classes `0, 1, 2, 3`. Which corresponds to which?

Comment: Is there some way to access the LabelEncoder object inside the LogisticRegression object?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The order will be same as returned by the `logit.classes_` (classes_ is an attribute of the fitted model, which represents the unique classes present in y) and mostly they will be arranged alphabetically in case of strings.

To explain it, we the above mentioned labels y on an random dataset with LogisticRegression:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

X = np.random.rand(45,5)
y = np.array(['GR3', 'GR4', 'SHH', 'GR3', 'GR4', 'SHH', 'GR4', 'SHH',
              'GR4', 'WNT', 'GR3', 'GR4', 'GR3', 'SHH', 'SHH', 'GR3', 
              'GR4', 'SHH', 'GR4', 'GR3', 'SHH', 'GR3', 'SHH', 'GR4', 
              'SHH', 'GR3', 'GR4', 'GR4', 'SHH', 'GR4', 'SHH', 'GR4', 
              'GR3', 'GR3', 'WNT', 'SHH', 'GR4', 'SHH', 'SHH', 'GR3',
              'WNT', 'GR3', 'GR4', 'GR3', 'SHH'], dtype=object)

lr = LogisticRegression()
lr.fit(X,y)

# This is what you want
lr.classes_

#Out:
#    array(['GR3', 'GR4', 'SHH', 'WNT'], dtype=object)

lr.coef_
#Out:
#    array of shape [n_classes, n_features]
```

So in the `coef_` matrix, the index 0 in rows represents the 'GR3' (the first class in `classes_` array, 1 = 'GR4' and so on.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a ton Vivek!

Comment: @Vivek can you also please explain how to get coefficients seperately for positive and negative class in binary problem i.e, clf.classes_ = [0, 1] and clf.coef_ = [[ some values]]