# How can I figure out which label each set of coefficients in LogisticRegression.coef_ maps to in sklearn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I've trained a number of Logistic Regression models for a project that I am working on. I've attained the coefficients of my features using the `coef` attribute. However, as I have four different target labels, the output consists of four sets of coefficients.

I've determined that each of these sets is a binary classifier for each label. How can I figure out which label each set maps to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I have found a solution.

Turns out that `LogisticRegression` has a `classes_` attribute which outputs an array of all of your different classes (in my case `[1,2,3,4]`). `coef_` outputs our weights and the classes that these weights map to is in the same order as `classes_`

[which coefficients go to which class in multiclass logistic regression in scikit learn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43622760/which-coefficients-go-to-which-class-in-multiclass-logistic-regression-in-scikit)